# Does not contain Scaffold error. I know that my method does not have a scaffold method but it is a child of a method which has scaffold

Tags: flutter

```
// On this noteItem long press i want to show a snackbar 
class NoteItem extends StatelessWidget { 
  NoteItem({Note note, this.removeNote}): note = note, super(key: ObjectKey(note)); 

  final Note note; 
  final RemoveNote removeNote; 

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){ 
    return ListTile( 
      onLongPress: () { 
    removeNote(note);
  },
  leading: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    child: Text(note.title[0]),
  ),
  title: Text(note.title),
);
  } 
} 

// This class gives the state`enter code here` 

class _NoteListState extends State<NoteList> { 

  void _addNote() { 
setState(() {
  widget.notes.add(Note(title: 'New Note', description: 'Successfully Added New Note'));
}); 
  } 

  void _removeNote(Note note) { 
setState(() {
  widget.notes.remove(note);
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar( content: Text('Note Deleted!'))); 
});
  } 

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){ 
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Notes List'),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
    children: widget.notes.map((Note note) {
      return NoteItem(
          note: note,
        removeNote: _removeNote,
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _addNote,
      tooltip: 'Add Note',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
);
  } 
}
```

If you want to look at the full code go to this link:- https://pastebin.com/h5HJWwdg

I tried to return a scaffold from the NoteItem but then after getting error realized that you can't do that. Also tried using builder that was also not working. It would be helpful if you direct to some documentation if possible so i can avoid these kind of mistakes in future.

I'm learning Flutter and just started with it few days ago so it would be helpful if you also tell if the way I am working on the note app correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method _removeNote (where you are trying to get the Scaffold) is a property of NodeListState which is the state for NodeList.  NodeList probably does not have a Scaffold above it in the tree.  It however has a Scaffold as a child.

Here is what I do.

Create a property in NodeList

```
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Assign it to the key property of my Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
```

Then get the Scaffold like this...

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
   content: new Text("Select player"),
));
```